# To define a measure, is it sufficient to define how to integrate continuous function?

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

Let me make my question clear. I want to define a measure $\mu$ on a space $X$. But instead of telling you what value I assign for some subset of $X$ (measurable sets that form a $\sigma$-algebra), I tell you that for each $f$ continuous, what $\int_X f(x)d\mu (x)$ is.

Then, is this measure uniquely determined? I know if I tell you how to integrate all measurable functions, then this measure is of course uniquely determined. Because integrate characteristic functions will give you measure of that respective set. But is it also true if I only define integration with continuous functions?

Comment: What is the topology on $X$?

Comment: This is the Daniell Integral approach.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In general this is false.  Here are some examples to think about:

1. If the $\sigma$-algebra on $X$ is not the Borel $\sigma$-algebra, there is generally no hope.  (What if $X$ has the trivial topology but the $\sigma$-algebra is not trivial?)  Hence you should restrict your attention to Borel measures.
2. Take $X = \{a,b\}$ with the topology $\tau = \{\emptyset, \{a\}, \{a,b\}\}$. The Borel $\sigma$-algebra is $2^X$ but the only continuous functions $f : X \to \mathbb{R}$ are constant, so $\mu_1 = \delta_a$ and $\mu_2 = 2 \delta_a - \delta_b$ agree on all continuous functions.  Thus you probably want a Hausdorff space.
3. Take $X = \mathbb{R}$.  Let $\mu$ be counting measure and $\nu = 2\mu$.  So you probably want to look at $\sigma$-finite measures.
4. As I mentioned in the above comment, on $X = \omega_1 + 1$ (which is compact Hausdorff), one can find two distinct finite measures which agree on all continuous functions.

However, here is a positive result.

> **Proposition.** Let $\mu, \nu$ be *finite* Borel measures on a metric space $(X,d)$.  If $\int f d\mu = \int f d\nu$ for all bounded continuous $f$, then $\mu = \nu$.

*Proof*.  Let $E$ be a closed set, and let $f_n(x) = \max\{1 - n d(x,E), 0\}$. You can check that $f_n$ is continuous and $f_n \downarrow 1_E$ as $n \to \infty$.  So by dominated convergence, $\mu(E) = \nu(E)$, and $\mu, \nu$ agree on all closed sets.

Now we apply [Dynkin's $\pi$-$\lambda$ theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynkin_system).  Let $\mathcal{P}$ be the collection of all closed sets; $\mathcal{P}$ is closed under finite intersections, and $\sigma(\mathcal{P})$ is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{B}$.  Let $\mathcal{L} = \{ A \in \mathcal{B} \colon \mu(A) = \nu(A)\}$.  Using countable additivity, it is easy to check that $\mathcal{L}$ is a $\lambda$-system, and we just showed $\mathcal{P} \subset \mathcal{L}$.  So by Dynkin's theorem, $\mathcal{B} = \sigma(\mathcal{P}) \subset \mathcal{L}$, which is to say that $\mu,\nu$ agree on all Borel sets, and hence are the same measure.

Comment: This is a really nice answer, Nate! Thank you.

Comment: An alternative way to conclude the proposition's proof is by regularity of finite Borel measures on metric spaces: the measure of Borel sets can be approximated by closed sets from below, so if $\mu=\nu$ on closed sets then they agree on all Borel sets. But Dynkin is ofcourse also very neat.

Comment: @ThomasE.: Well, I would probably use Dynkin's theorem to prove the regularity also :)

Comment: Yeah; there's no doubt that Dynkin is a powerful tool :-) You could, however, also prove it manually by showing that the collection of sets for which such approximation holds true is a $\sigma$-algebra that contains Borel sets. But as you said, Dynkin probably does the job easier.

Comment: @NateEldredge, just to make sure, you're not applying the DCT with $1_E$ as the dominating function, right? You need to apply it on $1_F$ with $F$ being some enveloping set around $E$ of distance $1$. Is this correct?

Comment: @PPR: These are finite measures, so you may just use 1 as your dominating function.

Comment: @NateEldredge it would be to sufficent to have the measures being the same on the indicatior functions right?

Comment: @user1: Yes, then it would be obvious.  But that isn't so relevant to the current question because indicator functions are not continuous.

Comment: @Nate Eldredge is your proposition still true for any finite signed measure?

Comment: @Prof.Hijibiji: Yes, and with the same proof.  The dominated convergence theorem is valid for signed measures if the dominating function is integrable with respect to the total variation measure, which is the case here.

Comment: But how to go from closed set to all of measurable set? My measure may not be regular.@Nate Eldredge

Comment: @Prof.Hijibiji: Which specific step of the proof do you think might fail?  I have not assumed that the measure is regular.  (Keep in mind that what I am claiming is that the result applies to every finite signed Borel measure on a metric space.  If you have non-metrizable spaces in mind, then all bets are off.)

Comment: I am asking is it true for non-borel finite signed measure? How to go from closed set to any measurable set?

Comment: @Prof.Hijibiji: For a measure that's not a Borel measure, the question doesn't really make sense.  You really need the measure defined on a $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{F}$ that's at least as large as the Borel $\sigma$-algebra in order to guarantee that continuous functions are measurable at all.  Conversely, the identity $\int f\,d\mu = \int f\,d\nu$ for all bounded continuous $f$ will be true for any two measures that agree on the Borel sets, even if they should differ on some non-Borel sets.

Comment: In $\mathbb{R}$ consider the sigma algebra consisting of all  $\mu$-measurable set where $\mu$ is a finite (may not positive, and may not borel measure) measure on $\mathbb{R}$. For this measure can we get similar kind of result?

Comment: Hey @Nate Eldredge, if we apply dominated convergence theorem then we will have $\int f_n d|\beta|\to \int 1_E d|\beta|$ where $\beta= \mu-\nu$ but we can't say $\int f_n d|\beta|=0$ from the given hypothesis.

Comment: @Prof.Hijibiji: If your $\sigma$-algebra is not the Borel one, or something closely related, then you are really not using the topology of $X$, and there is no reason why continuous functions should play any kind of special role.  I suppose you can work with the completions of Borel measures and get the same result, but if your measures are not related to the Borel $\sigma$-algebra in some way then I see no hope for a result like this.

Comment: @Prof.Hijibiji: The dominated convergence argument for signed measures goes as follows: let $\mu$ be a finite signed measure and $|\mu|$ its total variation.  By Radon-Nikodym, we have $d\mu = h \,d|\mu|$ for some $h \in L^1(|\mu|)$.  Now since $|f_n| \le 1$ and $f_n \to 1_E$ pointwise, we have $|f_n h| \le |h|$ and $f_n h \to 1_E h$ pointwise.  So applying dominated convergence with respect to $|\mu|$, using $|h|$ as the dominating function, we have $$\int f_n\,d\mu = \int f_n h \,d|\mu| \to \int 1_E h\,d|\mu| = \int 1_E \,d\mu.$$

Answer (score 8):

Check out the Riesz Representation Theorem, for example in $\textit{Real and Complex Analysis}$ by Rudin page 40. At least in the form presented in Rudin, if $X$ is a locally compact Hausdorff space and $\Lambda$ is a positive linear functional on $C_c(X)$, the continuous functions with compact support, then there exists a unique sigma algebra and a unique measure on the algebra such that $\int_X f \ d\mu = \Lambda(f)$ for all $f \in C_c(X)$.

Comment: A unique *Radon* measure.  It is possible that there are also non-Radon measures $\nu$ for which $\int f d\mu = \int f d\nu$ for all continuous $f$.  The classic example is on $X = \omega_1 + 1$.  This is Exercise 7.15 in Folland's *Real Analysis*.

Comment: The part of the proof which shows uniqueness of $\mu$ is nice and fits the OP's question very well: it shows that if $\int f\,d\mu=\int f\,d\nu$ for all $f\in C_{c}(X)$ then $\mu=\nu$. It's done basicly with Urysohn's lemma, and you also need regularity of $\mu,\nu$ or Dynkin's theorem in the proof, which Rudin does not specify explicitly. He just says it is enough to deal closed sets which, however, isn't a trivial remark.