# Equivalent condition on marginals

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, optimal-transport

Let $\mu$ be a probability measure on $X$ (compact), $v$ a probability measure on $Y$ (compact), and let $\gamma$ be a probability measure on $X \times Y$: if
$$\forall \psi \in C(X), \int_X \psi(x)d\mu=\int_{X \times Y} \psi(x)d\gamma$$
then $(\pi^x)_{*}\gamma=\mu$ (so, $\mu(\cdot)=\gamma((\pi^{x})^{-1}(\cdot))$, where $\pi^x$ represents the projection on $X$. The statement is analogous, mutatis mutandis, with respect to $Y$ and $v$. 
I have been able to prove the opposite direction of the statement by a usual chain of reasoning in measure theory but I am stuck on this direction. 
At a certain point I'd like to obtain something like "for all B measurable in X, then $\mu(B)=\gamma(B\times Y)$", but I cannot insert immediately an indicator function in the integrals since it would not satisfy the continuity on $X$ assumption.

Comment: I have already done this. I have to prove the implication going in the opposite sense.

Comment: In general as long as you have Borel regularity (which you get from Borel+finite measure in the metric space setting) you can approximate your indicator functions with continuous functions.  Without regularity what you are trying to prove will not always be true.  See this answer. https://math.stackexchange.com/a/155807/1210477